# Converting N1Ql query having “where” clause with “IN” parameters into mapreduce views

Tags: couchbase, sql++, couchbase-java-api

I have a plain `select` query for which `mapreduce` view is already present.

Query:

```
select count(*) from `my-bucket` where type = 'Order' and status = 'CREATED' and timestamp > 1535605294320 and timestamp <= 1535605594320
```

view:

```
function (doc, meta) {
    if (doc._class == "com.myclass.Order"){
        emit([doc.type,doc.status, doc.timestamp], null);
    }   
}
```

Keys for querying the view:

```
Start key : ["Order","CREATED",1535605294320]  
End key : ["Order","CREATED",1535605594320]
```

**Requirement**: Now, we would want this view to support a query having `IN` clause on `status` parameter. Also, we would like to add additional parameters supporting `IN` parameters. Sample `N1Ql` would be like below.

```
select count(*) from `my-bucket` where type = 'Order' and orderType IN ["TYPE-A","TYPE-B","TYPE-C"]and status IN ['CREATED',""READY,"CANCELLED"] and timestamp > MILLIS("2016-05-15T03:59:00Z") and timestamp <= MILLIS("2017-05-15T03:59:00Z")
```

How to write a query on view to accomplish this? Only solution comes to my mind is to fire multiple (lets says x) queries on views

```
where x = m1*m2*....*mn   
AND m1=number of paremeters in first IN clause 
AND n=number of IN clauses.
```

Is there any better solution like executing this query in batch (using `java` SDK) or a single `mapreduce` query?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are mixing N1QL queries and views? Views are the old functionality, and will be deprecated soon. Why not try to do this in straight N1QL?

Comment: @JohanLarson We are using community edition version of couchbase. As i given to understand, views are being used for performance perspective for getting counts of the number of records to be returned by the API. For actual data queries, we are using N1Ql queries itself.